# hierarical numbering in microsoft word 2003

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003, numbering

I have a headline in my document of level 3 and want the document hierarical numbered but it seems my level 3 headings do restart numbering at 1.1.1 and i have no clue why.

it looks like that:

```
1. blah
1.1 blub
1.2 blub
2. blah
2.1 blub
2.2 blub
1.1.1 blubb <- shouldnt this be 2.2.1 ?
3. blah
```

how can I correct this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to right click on the affected paragraph, select `Bullets and Numbering...`

Ensure that you are using an `Outline Numbered` setting and that the `Continue previous list` option is selected.

[image]

If this is already set up correctly then click on the `Customise` button and ensure that the `Number format` box has grey highlighted numbers - this denotes that they are using a `Previous level number` setting

[image]

If you can't see any grey highlighted numbers then you can recreate it as follows:

1. Delete all the text in the Number format box
2. Select `Level 1` from `Previous level number` drop down
3. Type `.` (or whichever separator you wish)
4. Select `Level 2` from `Previous level number` drop down
5. Type `.` (or whichever separator you wish)
6. Select `3` from the `Level` list
7. Select `1, 2, 3, ...` from the `Number style` drop down
8. Type `.` (or whichever trailing you wish)

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem now is that the "restart numbering" and "continue previous list" radiobuttons are greyed out.

Comment: @cody - the paragraph seems to have got completely lost from the numbering sequence. You could try going to the end of the previous numbered paragraph and carriage return to give you a new line (2.3 following your example) and then tab to indent one level to 2.2.1. Then copy/paste your paragraph to this new line.